# Installation of octsympy of Octave: error even after OK sympref diagnose

Tags: python, octave

I am finding problems with the installation of the symbolic package octsympy of Octave.

I have GNU Octave Version 5.2.0 under Windows 10. I have python3 installed with Anaconda.

I have followed the following steps:

1. Download the file `symbolic-2.9.0.tar.gz`.
2. Install with `pkg install symbolic-2.9.0.tar.gz`.
3. `pkg load symbolic`.
4. `setenv PYTHON C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python`.
5. `sympref diagnose`.

After the last command, I receive the message: Your kit looks good for running the Symbolic package.

However, when I try any symbolic command such as `sym('1/2')`, I receive error messages:

```
AttributeError: module 'sympy.core.compatibility' has no attribute 'integer_types'

error: Python exception: AttributeError: module 'sympy.core.compatibility' has no attribute 'integer_types' occurred while copying variables to Python.

error: called from pycall_sympy__ at line 191 column 5; sym at line 484 column 11
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: is this relevant to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354154/octave-4-2-2-and-sympy-1-6

Comment: some other mentions https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19877 https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444129  It sounds like this has to do with either your particular version of python (2 vs 3) and/or the sympy version installed. I wouldn't be surprised if this is an issue with the specific configuration in anaconda. Have you tried with standard pip?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou The two answers indicate that the problem is indeed related to the sympy version. I also used pip and the default python in Windows to avoid the Anaconda installation. The error repeats in the same way. The solution seems to be downgrading the sympy version. I prefer not to do this. I will use sympy through python instead of through Octave. Thank you. If you want to include your comments as an answer, I will accept it. Best

Comment: This issue has been reported as a bug: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/1023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been reported as a bug: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/1023. The developer indicated that it will be fixed in a new release.

If this issue is urgent, the solution is to downgrade the version of SymPy.

If this issue is not urgent, an option is to wait for a new release of octsympy.